# Evaluate $|(2\vec{a}+3\vec{b})\times(3\vec{a}+2\vec{b})|$

Tags: cross-product

Evaluate $$|(2\vec{a}+3\vec{b})\times(3\vec{a}+2\vec{b})|$$ when $|\vec{a}|=2,\space|\vec{b}|=3$ and the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I've got algebra lectures years ago and don't remember the algorithm. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hint: Products distribute and the cross product of a vector with itself is $0$.  Then remember that $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=-\vec{b}\times\vec{a}$.  Finally, use the formula for the length of the cross product as $|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\sin(\text{angle between})$.

Comment: So, as I understood:

$$|(2\vec{a}+3\vec{b})\times(3\vec{a}+2\vec{b})|=|6\vec{a} \times \vec{a} + 4 \vec{a} \times \vec{b} + 9 \vec{b} \times \vec{b} + 6 \vec{b} \times \vec{b}|=|5 \vec{b} \times \vec{a}|=5|\vec{b} \times \vec{a}|=5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}{2}=15 \sqrt{2}$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS:**

The cross product is distributive, i.e. ${\bf a} \times ({\bf b}+{\bf c}) = ({\bf a} \times {\bf b}) + ({\bf a} \times {\bf c})$. A similar result is true for $({\bf a} + {\bf b})\times{\bf c}$.

The cross product is anti-commutative, i.e. ${\bf a} \times {\bf b} = -({\bf b} \times {\bf a})$.

The magnitude of the cross product is given by $\|{\bf a} \times {\bf b}\| = \|{\bf a}\|\|{\bf b}\| \left|\sin\theta \right|$ where $\theta$ is the angle between ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$ in the plane spanned by ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$.

Comment: Since the angle between two vectors is at most $\pi$, you don't need the absolute values.